# Faker gem: possible to seed with stylized text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, seeding

I use the Faker gem to seed my db with fake data. For some variables I for example use `Faker::Lorem.paragraph(4)`. But what I would really want is to seed with text that has styling in it. Such as `<p></p><b>` etc. Is this possible with the Faker gem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(4)`. It returns an array, which you can then modify as needed. 
Like:

```
Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(4).map{|pr| "<p>#{pr}</p>"}.join
```